# Install Opera extension from registry

Tags: opera, opera-extension

I have developed a Opera extension. It's working fine. But I need to install my extension in the Windows registry or Windows file system. How can I to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> > NOTE: THIS QUESTION IS OPERA 12 RELATED
> >     Opera 12 uses another extension architecture than the following Opera versions!

Opera extensions aren't installed via the registry.

You will find a XML-file called `widget.dat` in the folder:

```
C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Opera\Opera\widgets
```

Each widget has an entry there. I think you'll understand the syntax yourself, it is quite self-explaining if you have some widgets installed.

---

EDIT: I just found out that adding a new entry to `widget.dat` will install the extension to Opera, but it will be deactivated as it hasn't been initialised. This usually happens through the javascript/extension engine during runtime.

To enable the script manually, there must be a `prefs.dat` in the folder `wuid-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` noted in the widget.dat, containing at least the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preferences>
  <section id="ui">
    <value id="default-prefs-applied" xml:space="preserve">1</value>
  </section>
</preferences>
```

Additionally to that, you may have to manually initialise the widget settings within the `pstorage` folder. The settings are stored as base64-encoded utf-16 key-value pair strings.
So, this encoded structure:

```
<ws>
  <e>
    <k>YQBsAGUAcgB0AF8AYgB1AGIAYgBsAGUAXwB0AGkAbQBlAG8AdQB0AA==</k>
    <v>IgAxADUAIgA=</v>
  </e>
<ws>
```

Reads as:

```
<widgetsettings>
  <entry>
    <key>alert_bubble_timeout</key>
    <value>"15"</value>
  </entry>
<widgetsettings>
```

(Tag names are freely interpreted ;) I found a base64 en/decoder capable of processing utf-16 [here](http://www5.rptea.com/base64/)

---

PS: Opera will install widgets by double-clicking them. So you could also execute Opera with the extensions path on the commandline. Opera will do everything for you then.

```
C:\Program Files\Opera\opera.exe C:\Path\To\Extension.oex
```

Comment: I am install extension for many browsers with my desktop programm. How i can install extension in silent mode?

Comment: I edited my answer above, I'm always happy for votes if this helps you ;)

Comment: Big Thanks! It's helpfull for me, but i am have small reputation to vote for you question =((

Comment: If you can, tell me where you found this information, I climbed everything, including the Opera forums and found nothing = (

Comment: I just derived it from the folder structure, all done by myself =) Unfortunately (for us at least) these things aren't documented.